# Regression analysis with time series data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

I'm completely stuck. I'm making a regression analysis in Python :

my dependent variable - share price of company,

independent variables - price of steel, price of coal and changing in local currency.

According theory I can't use this time series depended and independent variables due to autocorrelation.

Can I solve this problem by taking percent changing day-to-day of share price and percent changing day-to-day independed variable ? I have check this data for stationarity with Dickey Fuller test and get appropriate results, but I think that isn't right way.

or

What are the ways to build such a model ?

P.S I'm recently read that for time series data ARMA model is the good choice, but I don't understand how take in account independent variable, not predict on dependent variables on itself.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Conventional wisdom suggests that you should use ARCH (GARCH) models rather than OLS or ARIMA models, for the modeling of returns (percent change in prices). The literature of those models is very vast, but basically the starting model should be a GARCH(1,1).